# How i will get the latest record with average score

Tags: mysql, sql

I had this table
[image: I had this table]

I need the table in this format
[image]

my sql query is

```
SELECT ID,NAME,SEM,MARKS AS FINAL_MARKS,avg(marks) as avg_score
FROM STUDENT
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM STUDENT GROUP BY NAME)
group by Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` and `AVG` analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY SEM DESC) rn,
              AVG(MARKS) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AVGMARKS
    FROM STUDENT
)

SELECT ID, NAME, SEM, MARKS AS FINAL_MARKS, AVGMARKS AS AVG_SCORE
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello use the the following query:

```
select max(ID),
       NAME,
       SEM,
       MARKS AS FINAL_MARKS, 
       avg(marks) as avg_score
from STUDENT 
group by Name
order by 1 ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have use general syntax so no need of any documentation and answer is correct there is no issues.

Comment: @SalmanHussain your query would give the following error `Expression  of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column  SEM , MARKS  which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` , so your answer it is not correct

Answer (score 0):

If your `MySQL` version does not support windows function and `ID` column is auto_increment  you can use:

```
SELECT t1.ID,t1.NAME,SEM,MARKS as Final_marks, t1.avg_score
FROM STUDENT
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(ID) as ID,
                    NAME,
                    avg(MARKS) as avg_score
                    FROM STUDENT
                   GROUP BY NAME
           ) as t1 on t1.ID=STUDENT.ID;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> ID    NAME    SEM Final_marks avg_score
> 4     ALOK     4    34         30.2500
> 7     ROHIT    3    34         44.6667
> 9     SANDEEP  2    34         38.5000
> 10    HASSAN   1    23         23.0000
> ```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=daa87df7a182f52c537e0d1cad88d8e4

Answer (score -1):

Hello please try something like the following:

```
SELECT s.ID,
       s.NAME, 
       s.SEM,
       s.MARKS AS FINAL_MARKS,
       (Select avg(s1.marks) 
        from students s1 
        where s1.NAME = s.NAME 
       ) as avg_score
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE ID IN ( SELECT MAX(s2.ID) 
              FROM STUDENT s2 
              WHERE s2.NAME = s.NAME
             )
```